# How to combine multiple csvs using Python and include filename as entry in column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have multiple csvs that I want to combine using Python/pandas. However, I need the filename of each of the csvs to be included in the output as an entry in a new 'filename' column.

For example:

csv files:

- QB305707.csv
- QB305708.csv
- QB305709.csv

Columns in each csv:

| Id | voltage | current |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 151616 | 242 | 1.5 |
| 151617 | 240 | 1.4 |

Expected output after combining all csv's:

| Id | voltage | current | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151616 | 242 | 1.5 | QB305707 |
| 151617 | 240 | 1.4 | QB305707 |
| 151618 | 242 | 1.5 | QB305708 |
| 151619 | 240 | 1.4 | QB305708 |
| 151620 | 242 | 1.5 | QB305709 |
| 151621 | 240 | 1.4 | QB305709 |

Thank you for any help.

Comment: you can use  **os** module to combine the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.assign` while reading the files in loop or `keys` in `pd.concat`:

```
list_of_files = ['path\QB305707.csv','path\QB305708.csv','path\QB305709.csv']
out = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename=file) for file in list_of_files))
```

Or using `keys` which creates a seperate level of index with the filename

```
pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file) for file in list_of_files),keys=list_of_files )
```

If you dont already have the list of files in the folder , you can use the below snippet first to get the list of files:

```
import glob
list_of_files  = glob.glob(r'path_to_folder\*.csv')
```

So final code looks like:

```
import glob
import os
list_of_files  = glob.glob(r'path_to_folder\*.csv')
out = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(file).assign(filename=os.path.split(file)[-1])
                 for file in list_of_files))
```

Comment: Hi @anky. This worked well! I had to create a list of column names and add them to the dataframe to get rid of some formatting issues I had. I used these arguments: `pd.read_csv(file, names=column_names, header=None)` After that it worked perfectly. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

While @anky's solution is ideally correct, I think it can also be achieved by the following:

After importing your CSV files one by one, do the following:

```
filename1 = os.path.basename("path/to/file/QB305707.csv")
csv1Data = pd.read_csv(filename1)
# Assuming you did this with different variable names for each file

dfcsv1Data['filename'] = filename1
# Do this for all three DFs and simply concat / append all three dataframes together
```